# Assigning ofstream to ostream

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream, assign

I have to write a "logon" and a "logoff" function which redirect the current iostream from a function to a fstream and back.

To be more specific, I have:

```
void console (istream& in, ostream& out)
{
    //take command from user through console
    //default input/ output stream is in/out
}

void logon (ostream& out, string filename)
{
    ofstream fileout;
    fileout.open(filename);
    //assign this fstream fileout to ostream& out
}

void logoff (ostream& out)
{
    // take current ofstream fileout
    fileout.close();
    // return the stream back to out
}
```

The program should work like this:

- User enter some commands: Output to console
- User enter logon filename command: create a file and redirect output to that file
- User enter some commands: Output to file
- User enter logoff: Close file, redirect output back to console
  I know that ofstream is a part of ostream but don't know how to manipulate between the two. 
  Please help, any input is appreciated.

Comment: I want to do something similar. I have a logging module that outputs to std::cout but I want to programs using the library to be able to specify to log to file instead. However when my program creates a std:;ostream and passes it to my module, my module cannot store it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a std::string as an intermediary:

```
void consoleIn (std::istream& in, std::string& strInput)
{
in >> strInput;
}

void logon (std::ostream& out, std::string filename, std::string const& MyText)
{
std::ofstream fileout;
fileout.open(filename);
fileout << MyText;
}
```

And btw try to use std:: to specify standard objects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a string stream as an intermediary?

```
stringstream ss;
while ofstream has data
    ofstream >> ss
    ostream << ss
....
```

Just an idea, not sure how practical this would be